# Support function of closed convex set and subset

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis

Let $B$ be a closed and convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. Define the support function of $B$ as $S_B(y)=\sup\{y^T x \mid x \in B\}$. Can we say that $A\subseteq B$ if and only if $S_A(y)\leq S_B(y)$ for all $y\in \mathbb{R}^n$?

The forward direction is trivial. For the reverse, we can say that if $x\in A\setminus B$ then we can find some $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$ that strictly separates $x$ and $B$. Then $S_A(a) \geq a^T x > a^Tz$ for all $z \in B$. Now if $B$ is also bounded (that is $B$ is compact) then we have a contradiction since the supremum in the definition of the support function of $B$ becomes maximum and then we would have $S_A(a) > S_B(a)$. The same argument does not work when $B$ is not assumed bounded because the strict inequality becomes non-strict when taking supremums. So we can only conclude that $S_A(a) \geq S_B(a)$ and we somehow have to rule out the equality case.

Is the result even true when $B$ is just closed? If yes, how can one proceed with the proof? If not, is there a counterexample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $B$ is closed, its complement is open. Take $x \in B^c$, then there is $\rho>0$ such that $\{ z: \ \|x-z\|\le \rho\} \subset B^c$. Then separate the ball and $B$: there is $a\ne0$ such that
$$
a^Tz \ge a^Ty
$$
for all $y\in B$ and $z$ with $\|x-z\|\le \rho$. Set $z:= x  - \frac\rho{\|a\|}a$. Then
$$
a^Tx - \rho \|a\| \ge a^Ty,
$$
which implies
$$
a^Tx \ge S_B(a) + \rho \|a\|,
$$
and if $x\in A\setminus B$ then $S_A(a) \ge a^Tx \ge S_B(a) + \rho \|a\|$.